# Upload file created with fopen to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3, fopen

I have some PHP code that I use to loop through a database query and create a CSV file. 
The file is created with `fopen()` and downloaded at the end of the routine. No problem with that. 
However, at the end of the CSV creation I try to push a file to an S3 bucket using that same generated content (`$output`).

It fails with the following message:

*AWS Error Type: server, AWS Error Message: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.7.27 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.47.0 PHP/7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.9 thrown in /www/MIND/gen6portal/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91*

I know it has to do with me trying to pass the stream as the body of the S3 key but I don't know how else to do this. Any pointers are appreciated. 
Here's the code:

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($output, $rows); // there's some more processing that I do but this works fine
}

//Now I want to upload it to S3: 

$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key' => 'myfile.csv',
    'Body' => $output,
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
]);

fclose($output);
```

Interesting enough, if I simply try to get an existing file (to validate that I have access to that S3 bucket) it uploads just fine:

```
s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key' => "myfile.csv",
    'Body' => fopen('temp.csv', 'rb'),
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
            ]);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put it to a temp file and then upload that temp file to S3?

Answer (score 3):

As [per the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) the stream `php://output` is a write-only stream, therefore you can not read from it again.

However, you could use a temp stream, like so:

```
$output = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    fputcsv($output, $rows);
}
rewind($output);

$s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key' => 'myfile.csv',
    'Body' => stream_get_contents($output),
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
]);

fclose($output);
```

Disclaimer: I did not test that yet, shout if you run into further trouble.

P.S.: Note I changed the mode for the handle to `w+` in order to have it readable too.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried the temp file approach but I run into a "Access denied" issue: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\AccessDeniedException: AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 07AA8C5530D16350, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Access Denied, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.7.27 Guzzle/3.9.3 curl/7.47.0 PHP/7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.9 thrown in /www/MIND/gen6portal/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 91

Comment: I know I have write access to that bucket, if I try to upload an existing file from the server via PHP it works fine.

Comment: What does that have to do with using a memory stream?

Comment: So did you try it with a memory stream or with a temprary file? Memory should not have any permission issues at all since it happens inside the PHP process.

Comment: I tried with a temporary file and a memory stream and got the same access denied error. It's like S3 doesn't like what I'm trying to upload.But I am 100% sure I have the right permissions for it.

Comment: @PauloHgo Do you actually have permission to create an object in that bucket with the credentials you’re using…?

Comment: @Martin Bean Yes, I do. I have edited the question to show that it works fine from an existing file. If I try to create a temp file (like temp.csv) it still doesn't let me do it after having populated the file via `fputcsv()`

Comment: My guess is that S3 does not like what you are trying to store (e.g. empty file). Did you try and do a  `var_dump(stream_get_contents($output));`  before the putObject call? Does the content look like you expect it to be?

Comment: A `var_dump()` shows the correct contents for the stream.

Comment: Bear in mind that `w+` is an invalid mode, this code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should fclose() the file before you try to send it to S3. If the file writing is still open the file is still in use and unavailable.